# Passing parameters when a google spreadsheet is opened in a browser

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there a way to pass parameters to a google spreadsheet url from another spreadsheet?

For example, in spreadsheet A I am using =hyperlink to spreadsheet B but I would like to pass parameters that will be caught by a function in a script which resides in spreadsheet B.

The idea is that a user will invoke this url in a cell and basic information will be populated accordingly in the other spreadsheet that will be opened to this user.

Any ideas how to achieve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible using spreadsheet url params.
you want to put links on spreadsheet #1 which act on spreadsheet #2:
You could publish a script in the 2nd spreadsheet, and place links (with params) on the 1st spreadsheet using the service url in the 2nd. That script then does what you need. There you can get the container spreadsheet and write to it. You can also write a gui there that shows data and a link to the container spreadsheet (2nd)